# Use WCF to receive any XML message from an MSMQ Queue?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, msmq

I have an MSMQ that receives XML format messages from various sources.  I have a WCF endpoint (using MsmqIntegrationBinding) that I want to receive these messages.  I defined the following:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://TestApp.MSMQService", ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None)]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(String))]
public interface IMsmqReceiverService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
    void SubmitQueueMessage(MsmqMessage<String> msg);
}
```

Hoping that would receive any XML message, however it only receives messages formated:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<string>message</string>
```

For various reasons we don't know, and don't want to know, the schema of the xml message, getting it into a String would be sufficient.  How can I define an endpoint that recieves XML messages with any nodes that arrive on the queue regardless of the schema used in the message?

Additionally, given a String buffer containing the XML of a message, how can I put that onto a MSMQ using System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Send without it getting wrapped in additional xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the MSMQ integration, but try `MsmqMessage<XmlElement>`.

Don't manipulate XML as a string if you can possibly help it. Always use one of the many XML APIs.

Comment: Thanks John, that seems to have gotten it.

I don't want to manipulate the XML, don't even want to know the schema, I just need to pull it off the queue and send it on, hence why I thought I could get it as a string and avoid deserializing it.

This should ho the job though.  Thanks again!